# How to collect a login user's name after clicking on a SharePoint page and send to a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2010. Is there a way using SharePoint Designer to collect a login users name and date and send it to a list using a workflow?
It doesn't matter how many times they visit the page.

The chiefs did not like using analytics. They just want to have all the users of a group who log onto a page captured into a custom list. Categorized and archived.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with the Workflow. That cannot be triggered on a page visit. You could create javascript and put it on the page. The script could get the current user and store it in a SharePoint list using the CSOM/REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do it with Sharepoint Designer. But we've done this by writing a **custom web part** and placing it into the page. I believe you can call `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` to get the username.